# How to add Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) constraints to a Semidefinite program (SDP) in standard form

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Given an SDP problem with $m$ equality constraints and one Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) in standard form:

$$
\begin{align}
\min        \quad & \mathbf{F}_0 \bullet \mathbf{Y} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \mathbf{F}_i \bullet \mathbf{Y} = c_i \quad (i = 1,\ldots,m), \quad \mathbf{Y} \succeq \mathbf{0}, \\
                  & f(\mathbf{Y}) \succeq 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Where $\mathbf{F}_j$ are known matrices and $\mathbf{Y}$ is the unknown matrix, how can we include the LMI into the formulation? I'm interested in expressing it in the SDPA format [[Sec. 2.1 of this link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Masakazu-Kojima/publication/247456489_SDPA_SemiDefinite_Programming_Algorithm_User%27s_Manual_-_Version_600/links/5442248b0cf2a6a049a5e968/SDPA-SemiDefinite-Programming-Algorithm-Users-Manual-Version-600.pdf)]. In this format, we need to specify the matrices $\mathbf{F}_i$, as well as the constraint values $c_i$.

Since my problem above matches the dual in SDPA format (Eq. "SDP" in the previous link), except for the LMI, I am looking for a way to adapt it to inlcude an LMI.

I have thought of augmenting the matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ with a diagonal block corresponding to $f(\mathbf{Y})$:
$$
\begin{align}
\min \quad & \bar{\mathbf{F}}_0 \bullet \bar{\mathbf{Y}}, \quad \bar{\mathbf{Y}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{Y} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \mathbf{F}_i \bullet \mathbf{Y} = c_i 
\\
& \mathbf{Z} - f(\mathbf{Y}) = \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
$$
Where the expression $\mathbf{Z} - f(\mathbf{Y}) = \mathbf{0}$ would need to be expanded into multiple constraints corresponding to the individual elements of the symmetric matrix $\mathbf{Z}$.

By doing this, I believe we can ensure that $f(\mathbf{Y}) \succeq \mathbf{0}$ holds. However, I am unsure if there are better alternatives.